# add header with values in xlsx file

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10, epplus

I'm trying to add a new header and fill it with some values on existing xlsx file but nothing is written to the file.

```
using (ExcelPackage phone_package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filename)))
            {
                var phone_workbook = phone_package.Workbook;
                if (phone_workbook != null && phone_workbook.Worksheets.Any())
                {
                    var ws = phone_workbook.Worksheets.Add("Country");
                    var dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Columns.Add("Germany", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("Italy", typeof(string));
                    ws.Cells["G2:G"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
                    phone_package.Save();
                }
            }
        }
```

What am I missing? I'm new to EPPlus library.

Comment: Your DataTable needs some rows first, ofc.

Answer (score 1):

The EPPlus library starts filling a sheet from a starting point, a cell, so most people would start filling from the first one (A1) onwards. But if you prefer (G2), that should work as well.

PS: When creating a new ExcelPackage, you use the file path instead of the file name.

```
using (ExcelPackage phone_package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filepath)))
{
    var phone_workbook = phone_package.Workbook;
    if (phone_workbook != null && phone_workbook.Worksheets.Any())
    {
        ExcelWorksheet ws = phone_workbook.Worksheets.Add("Country");
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Germany", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Italy", typeof(string));
        ws.Cells["G2"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
        phone_package.SaveAs(filename);
    }
}
```